# Angular AJAX field validation

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

i would like to implement a "check username uniqueness" on angular, how can i do this ?
i've tried custom directives and ngRemoteValidation without success, i can intercept controller server-side only with ngRemoteValidation, but parameter is ever null.

my scope is to send a call to server onchange/exiting field and then if not valid disabling submit button.

(server-side is ASP.NET MVC)

server-side code :

```
 public NgRemoteValidationAnswer validazioneHardware(string codice_hardware){}
```

client-side code :

```
<input  type="text" name="codice_hardware"
                            class="form-control"    
                            ng-model="ViewModel.matricola.codice_hardware" 
                            required 
                            ng-remote-validate="validazioneHardware" 
                            />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct the server-side code with

```
 public NgRemoteValidationAnswer validazioneHardware(string value){}
```